# Refactoring processing of JSON attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an API processing a large number of attributes, the following pattern is frequent

```
      if !article[:ingredients].nil?
        clean_ingredients = article[:ingredients].tr('*$+!@#Â', ' ')
        ingredients = clean_ingredients.downcase.capitalize
      else
        ingredients = nil
      end
```

for a JSON string as: `{ "id": "YYYYYY", "article": [ { "ingredients": "long string", [...]`
Unfortunately, a method defined as

```
  def empty_and_clean(array_element, element_attribute)
      if !array_element[:element_attribute].nil?
        clean_ingredients = array_element[:element_attribute].tr('*$+!@#Â', ' ')
        ingredients = clean_ingredients.downcase.capitalize
      else
        ingredients = nil
      end  
  end
```

cannot be called in the method as `empty_and_clean(article, ingredients)`  as it returns
`undefined local variable or method 'ingredients'`

What syntax allows to refactor this pattern?

Comment: I think you are just missing an underscore in the method name. If that isn't the case, please show the full function definition.

Comment: Yes, that is correct; got jumbled up with the process and errors.  Question modified to a more pertinent topic.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be called in the method as empty_and_clean(article, ingredients)". What happens when you do?

Comment: correct.  updated

Comment: "as it returns..." The correct word is "throws" or "causes an error" or "gives" rather than "returns". "returns" is used when a function does its job correctly and gives back a valid result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your `empty_and_clean` method this way:

```
empty_and_clean(article, :ingredients)
```

Just modify `empty_and_clean` to use `element_attribute` directly rather than the symbol `:element_attribute`.

I suggest you read more about symbols in Ruby to understand how this works.

Also, `array_element` is a misleading name because it is an array, not an element of an array. `array` would be slightly better, but is still too generic. Maybe `objects` or something else that describes what is actually in the array.